# find duplicates of items endings in a list

Tags: python, list

I would like to find items in a list that have duplicate endings within the last 3 characters of the string

I know how to find duplicates using the code below, but need help with code how to find 
that the last strings of "sara" and "tamara" are the same so that one of the items can be copied to a duplicate_finding list

using the following code, I can only identifiy exact duplicate items of a list:

```
names = ["tom", "john", "sara" , "tamara" , "tom"]
single_finds = []
duplicate_finds = []

for i in names:
        if i in single_finds:
                duplicate_finds.append(i)
        else:
                single_finds.append(i)

print (single_finds)
print (duplicate_finds)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['tom', 'john', 'sara', 'tamara']
['tom']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach would be to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), specifying that we want to group based on the last `n` characters using the `key` argument.

Then we can flatten the list removing those sublists with only `1` item using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and take a set to remove duplicates (or a `list` if you want them):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
k = lambda x: x[-3:]
l = [list(v) for _,v in groupby(sorted(names, key=k), key=k)]
# [['tamara', 'sara'], ['john'], ['tom', 'tom']]
[i[0] for i in l if len(i) > 1]
# ['tamara', 'tom']
```

Comment: This only works coincidentally as `sara` and `tamara` are sorted next to each other in the list. You should sort by the last three characters instead. (As a general rule, the `key` to both `sorted` and `groupby` should be the same.)

Comment: Oh you're completely right i should be sorting with a key too thanks @tobias_k. Updated, nice catch

Comment: can you change the code so that ONLY the duplicate is printed (only "sara" OR "tamara") as I would like to delete all duplicates out of the original list ?

Answer (score 2):

Accumulate names per-suffix using a dict, and then gather the results:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict 
>>> d = defaultdict(list) 
>>> for name in names: 
...     suffix = name[-3:] 
...     d[suffix].append(name) 
... 
>>> for suffix, names in d.items(): 
...     print("-", suffix, ":", *names) 
... 
- tom : tom tom
- ohn : john
- ara : sara tamara
```

You can partition `d.items()` into singles and dupes by looking at the `len(names)` now.

This is an *O(n)* time-complexity solution, as opposed to groupby-based approaches which require pre-sorting the data at *O(n log n)*.

Answer (score 0):

Group the list by the last 3 characters by slicing the string from end, if the names group has more than an element in it then its a duplicate else its single.

```
import itertools

names = ["tom", "john", "sara" , "tamara" , "tom"]

def find_duplicates(names):
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(names), lambda x: x[-3:]):
        grouped_items = list(group)
        if len(grouped_items) > 1:
            yield grouped_items[0]

def find_single(names):
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(names)):
        if len(list(group)) == 1:
            yield key

single_finds = list(find_single(names))
duplicate_finds = list(find_duplicates(names))

print ("Single finds", single_finds)
print ("Duplicate finds", duplicate_finds)
```

Outputting:

```
Single finds ['john', 'sara', 'tamara']
Duplicate finds ['sara', 'tom']
```

Comment: but "john" should not be in the duplicate list

Comment: @sebastian20182018 sorry my bad

Answer (score 0):

To complete @wim linear time answer :

```
import collections
res=collections.defaultdict(list)

for name in names: 
    res[name[-3:]].append(name)

singles,dummies= [],[]

for v in res.values():
    singles.extend(v[:1])
    dummies.extend(v[1:])
```

Then :

```
singles is ['tom', 'john', 'sara']

dummies is ['tom', 'tamara']
```